# Xpath query issue using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xpath

I want to extract the links from this HTML file using Objective-C.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base href='http://example.com/' />
  <title>Example website</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='images'>
   <a href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /><img src='image1_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /><img src='image2_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /><img src='image3_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /><img src='image4_thumb.jpg' /></a>
   <a href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /><img src='image5_thumb.jpg' /></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

HEre is the Xpath Query:

```
//a[contains(@href, "image")]/@href
```

But the problem here is that it errors on Quotation marks around image text in query!

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to escape the double quotes to use them inside a quoted string:

```
@"//a[contains(@href,\"image\")]/@href"
```

Or use single quotes, if XPath supports that:

```
@"//a[contains(@href,'image')]/@href"
```

Comment: I TRIED YOUR both queries! it runs without error now, but it does not return the result, it return null!

Comment: How so? Does it say (null)? I don't know enough about XPath to verify your query.

Answer (score 1):

Since the XPath expression is delimited by double quote characters, you cannot use these characters inside of it. You'll have to switch to single quotes instead:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'image')]/@href
```

Comment: I TRIED YOUR both queries! it runs without error now, but it does not return the result, it return null!